# Full Width and Height on a one pager - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two sections on my page:

```
<div class="first">
//content #1
</div>
<div class="second">
//content #2
</div>
```

The first div should always fill the whole screen. The second div should be after this one.

I created a CSS like this:

```
.first {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
}

.second {
position: absolute;
top:100%;
}
```

This works, but is this the "correct" way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: One option - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/vs6me8hw/

Comment: You are looking for `vh` unit. [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/u6k78vos/)

Comment: one characteristic about position:absolute is that you take elements out of the flow (that's bad news for responsiveness)

Comment: Thanks. I created a wrapper with 100vh and 100vw, the image inside of that wrapper has a height and width of 100%. This is fine, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 100vh to size relative to the viewport. 100% is relative to it's parent and that might lead to some issues.

More info here http://demosthenes.info/blog/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design